# Get VirtualBox VM RAM usage through vboxapi

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, api, analysis

So, I'm working on a python application that reports information about a host running VirtualBox to a webserver. Therefore I am using [vboxapi](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/SDKRef.pdf). I can send information about the host with the following code:

```
from vboxapi import VirtualBoxManager
mgr = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)
vbox = mgr.vbox
host = vbox.host
log['host'] = {
    'processorCount': host.processorCount,
    'processorCoreCount': host.processorCoreCount,
    'processorOnlineCount': host.processorOnlineCount,
    'processorOnlineCoreCount': host.processorOnlineCoreCount,
    'memorySize': host.memorySize,
    'memoryAvailable': host.memoryAvailable,
}
send_to_webserver(log)
```

What I would like to do is send information about the running guests, such as RAM and CPU usage. I can retrieve the max available amount of RAM with `machine.memorySize`, but not the current usage. When going through the vboxapi documentation, this should be possible with the PerformanceCollector, but I can get this to work, neither can I find a working example. Can someone help me with this?

The necessary steps are on page 274 of the docs.

Ps. my host is a Windows machine, my guests are Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after all. Just in case anyone else is looking into this:

```
mgr = VirtualBoxManager(None, None)
vbox = mgr.vbox
# Enabling performance collection
perfomance_collector = self.vbox.performanceCollector
# Enable metrics (None = all metrics, None = all machines)
perfomance_collector.enableMetrics(None, None)
# Setup metrics (None = all metrics, None = all machines, 1 sample every second, keep up to 15 samples)
perfomance_collector.setupMetrics(None, None, 1, 15)

while True:
    # get metrics
    (values, names_out, objects_out, units, scales, sequence_numbers, indices, lengths) = perfomance_collector.queryMetricsData(None, None)
    out = []
    # process results
    for i in range(0, len(names_out)):
        scale = int(scales[i])
        if scale != 1:
            fmt = '%.2f%s'
        else:
            fmt = '%d %s'
        out.append({
            'name': str(names_out[i]),
            'object': str(objects_out[i]),
            'unit': str(units[i]),
            'scale': scale,
            'values': [int(values[j]) for j in range(int(indices[i]), int(indices[i]) + int(lengths[i]))],
            'values_as_string': '[' + ', '.join([fmt % (int(values[j]) / scale, units[i]) for j in range(int(indices[i]), int(indices[i]) + int(lengths[i]))]) + ']'
        })
    # print something useful
    for metric in out:
        print(metric['name'], metric['values_as_string'])
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: How do you run this script? Just `py <filename>` or such?

Comment: It's part of a larger application, but if you combine the code of my question and answer, it should work I guess.